# Easiest way to re-order answer key (list of correct answers)

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

I have a lot of answer keys that look like this:

```
1.A;8.C;15.E;22.B
2.B;9.D;16.A;23.C
3.C;10.E;17.B;24.D
4.D;11.A;18.C;25.E
5.E;12.B;19.D;26.A
6.A;13.C;20.E;27.B
7.B;14.D;21.A;28.C
```

I'm trying to find the easiest way to automatically re-order them all into something like this:

```
1.A
2.B
3.C
4.D
5.E
6.A
7.B
8.C
9.D
10.E
11.A
12.B
13.C
14.D
15.E
16.A
17.B
18.C
19.D
20.E
21.A
22.B
23.C
24.D
25.E
26.A
27.B
28.C
```

I don't have access to any programming languages. I've been trying to use Find-Replace in Notepad, Wordpad, Microsoft Word, and Notepad++, and trying to think of something I could do with AutoHotKey. But I can't think of anything that would work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Word 2010,

1. Hit Ctrl-H to Replace All ";" with "^p"
2. Hit Ctrl-A to select all
3. Click the icon for sorting at tab Home(I don't know the hotkey for this). In the Sort Text dialog, click button "Option...". At Separate fields at, select Other: and enter "." Then, click Ok to go back. At Sort by, select Field 1. At Type: select Number. Click OK to perform the sorting.

Optionally, record this as a macro and assign it with an hot-key.

Comment: I found this to be somewhat of an ingenious/easy/non-programming solution... very nice.  Where/how did you find that ^p would replace with a paragraph?

Comment: Glad that u find it helpful. In the replacing dialog, there s a checkbox for the paragraph character. If u ve ticked it, next time the ^p is already in the replacing box.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have access to any programming languages.

That's not true! You have [Windows Scripting Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), that allows you to write code in [VBScript, JavaScript and VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Available_scripting_engines) and [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/mt173057.aspx) which is a powerful scripting language with ability to tap into .Net.

Here is PowerShell solution. Save it as `SortAnswers.ps1` and run in the PowerShell session.

```powershell
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$InPath, # Input file

    [string]$OutPath # Output file, optional
)

# Natural sort implementation:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does
$ToNatural = {[regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) })}

$Sorted = Get-Content -Path $_ | # Read input file, line by line
    ForEach-Object {$_ -split ';'} | # Split every line by ';'
        Sort-Object $ToNatural # Sort resulting items and assign them to $Sorted variable

# If OutPath parameter specified
if($OutPath)
{
    # Save to file
    $Sorted | Set-Content -Path $OutPath
}
else
{
    # Display on screen
    $Sorted
}
```

#### Examples

- Read `Answers.txt` in current dir, save sorted answers to `Answers_sorted.txt`:

  ```
   .\SortAnswers.ps1 -InPath .\Answers.txt -OutPath .\Answers_sorted.txt

   or

   .\SortAnswers.ps1 .\Answers.txt .\Answers_sorted.txt
  ```
- Read `Answers.txt` in current dir, show sorted answers on screen:

  ```
   .\SortAnswers.ps1 -InPath .\Answers.txt

   or

  .\SortAnswers.ps1 .\Answers.txt
  ```

#### Note

You have to [allow the execution of PowerShell scripts](http://www.howtogeek.com/106273/how-to-allow-the-execution-of-powershell-scripts-on-windows-7/) first:

> The default execution policy of PowerShell is called Restricted. In
>   this mode, PowerShell operates as an interactive shell only. It does
>   not run scripts, and loads only configuration files signed by a
>   publisher that you trust. If you are getting the nasty red error the
>   most probable cause is that you are trying to run an unsigned script.
>
> To change it to unrestricted run the following command from an
>   administrative PowerShell:
>
> `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

#### References

- [How to sort by file name the same way Windows Explorer does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does)

Answer (score 0):

- I don't have yet enough points to comment so please people, don't hate and vote down. I am trying to give back to the community.

The **"easiest way"**:

I noted that you have MS Word, so it wouldn't be a stretch to assume that you have MS Excel also.

**Copy the text and paste it as-is into notepad** and **save it to the desktop, say as a.txt**.

Then **launch MS Excel**.

On this blank sheet navigate to the menu; **Data -> Import External Datd -> Import Data** (navigate to desktop and choose a.txt). 

Then click "open".

A text import wizard is now open. 

Choose radio selection '**Delimited**', Click 'Next'. 

Choose Delimiters box, '**Semicolon**'. 

Click Finish. Then accept by clicking OK.

You now have several columns of data, but arranged in order top-to-bottom as desired. In your example you will have 4 columns. Column A will be 1-7, B 8-14, etc. You can now copy each adjacent column and past it under column A to stack the data. Takes only a minute to do.

Hope this helps!

- I think this is the easiest approach as you mention that you "don't have access to program languages", which is to say that you aren't a programmer I take it. As a programmer you can easily download any one of many compilers and program a sort algorithm in several languages. But that would be writing a program.